# USPS API Not working

Tags: php, xml

I've tried several posted xml tests from stackoverflow.

from [USPS Address Validation Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955988/usps-address-validation-fail)

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="123USERID567"><Address ID="1"><Address1></Address1><Address2>10051+Orr+%26amp%3b+Day+Rd</Address2><City>santa+fe+springs</City><State>ca</State><Zip5>90670</Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>
```

from [USPS api - using curl and codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391110/usps-api-using-curl-and-codeigniter)

```
http://testing.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest USERID="xxxxxxx"><ZipCode ID= "0"><Zip5>90210</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>
```

These are the errors I get:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd think the error messages are pretty self explanatory?

Comment: Are you sure the post office is still open?

Comment: Are you actually setting the user id? You aren't using `USERID="xxxxxxx"`, right? Sorry for asking the obvious, but I have made my fair share of obvious mistakes. Otherwise, disregard.

Comment: @Jonathan like it shows in the images, I'm including one of the userids they provided. Thanks for making sure, though :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 3rd party support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once they moved me to production, it was fine.